# sailpoint installation -- I got error while installing iiq

Tags: xml

2022-06-04T10:40:13,042  WARN main springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:557 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'versionChecker' defined in class path resource [configBeans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to check IdentityIQ database version: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The server time zone value 'CDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.)
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'versionChecker' defined in class path resource [configBeans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to check IdentityIQ database version: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The server time zone value 'CDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.)

Comment: Hello Sabine, welcome to StackOverflow. I tried to improve your question but I don't see what is code, what is error lines and what is text. Can you make some efford to improve your question in formatting correctly code and error message ? To do this, you can use ``` sequence to format lines as code. I rate you to follow my advice because your question is unreadable. A little remark - a question is a sentence that ends with a ? character.

Comment: question is unreadable. Text is mixed with code or error message. I recommand to author to improve his question.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the hibernate layer could not connect to the database, the reason is due to the specifics of the DB driver. Use a jdbc client such as SQL Admin to determine the correct connection string for your DB, then update the iiq.properties file accordingly.